# Return parent node and next sibling while ordering using jQuery sortable table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table where my thead tags can be sorted ascendingly and descendingly.

while each table row has a collapse as a next sibling table row when sorted only the table row gets sorted without its next sibling which includes it's own collapse.

I've tried using `.nextElementSibling();` but the structure of the table gets messed up while rows are moved or getting sorted.

Here is my code snippet returning only the parent node without it's next sibling which i want to be ordered along with.

```js
//sortelements function
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function(){
    var sort = [].sort;
    
    return function(comparator, getSortable) {
        
        getSortable = getSortable || function(){return this;};
        
        var placements = this.map(function(){
            
            var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
                parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,
                
                // Since the element itself will change position, we have
                // to have some way of storing it's original position in
                // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
                nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                    document.createTextNode(''),
                    sortElement.nextSibling
                );
            
            return function() {
                
                if (parentNode === this) {
                    throw new Error(
                        "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
                    );
                }
                
                // Insert before flag:
                parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
                // Remove flag:
                parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);
                
            };
            
        });
       
        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
            placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });
        
    };
    
})();


$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#comparetable');

            $('.sortable')
                .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
                .each(function(){
            
                    var th = $(this),
                        thIndex = th.index(),
                        inverse = false;

                    th.click(function(){
                        table.find('td').filter(function(){
                            return $(this).index() === thIndex;
                        }).sortElements(function(a, b){
                                return parseInt($.text([a])) > parseInt($.text([b])) ? 
                                  inverse ? -1 : 1
                                  : inverse ? 1 : -1;
                        }, function(){
                            // parentNode is the element we want to move and the next element to be moved is to be added here.
                            return  this.parentNode;
                        });
            
                        inverse = !inverse;
                        
                       
                    });
                });
            });
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://www.hadbrok.com//assets/scripts/jquerysortabletable.js"></script>
</head>
 
 <body>
    <table id="comparetable" class="table table-striped-offer d-none d-sm-block">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Plan</th>
                <th class="text-center sortable headersortNeutral">Group Premium</th>
                <th style="white-space: pre-line;" class="text-center sortable headersortNeutral">In Patient</th>
                <th class="text-center sortable headersortNeutral">Out Patient</th>
                <th class="text-center sortable headersortNeutral">
                    Chronic &amp; Pre-existing disease</th>
                <th class="text-center sortable headersortNeutral">Medication</th>
                <th class="text-center sortable headersortNeutral">Dental</th>
                <th class="text-center sortable headersortNeutral">Optical</th>
                <th class="text-center sortable headersortNeutral">Maternity</th>
                <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <img src="https://www.hadbrok.com/uploads/hadbrok_medical_logos/beta/metlife2.png" style="width: 20px;" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>50,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>750,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>20,928<span></span>
                </td>   
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>30,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>50,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>83,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>34,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>54,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                        <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs waves-effect waves-light" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMEDICAL_5">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="11">
                    <div id="collapseMEDICAL_5" class="collapse" style="text-align: left; padding: 20px;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Class </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Network </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Family </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Physiotherapy </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Dental </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Optical </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Maternity </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Life insurance </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <img src="https://www.hadbrok.com/uploads/hadbrok_medical_logos/beta/metlife2.png" style="width: 20px;" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>250,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>120,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>30,928<span></span>
                </td>   
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>60,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>60,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>80,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>80,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>30,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                        <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs waves-effect waves-light" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMEDICAL_6">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="11">
                    <div id="collapseMEDICAL_6" class="collapse" style="text-align: left; padding: 20px;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Class </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Network </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Family </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Physiotherapy </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Dental </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Optical </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Maternity </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Life insurance </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <img src="https://www.hadbrok.com/uploads/hadbrok_medical_logos/beta/metlife2.png" style="width: 20px;" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>50,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>510,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>32,928<span></span>
                </td>   
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>54,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>66,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>75,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>23,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <span>24,928<span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                        <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs waves-effect waves-light" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMEDICAL_7">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="11">
                    <div id="collapseMEDICAL_7" class="collapse" style="text-align: left; padding: 20px;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Class </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Network </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Family </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Physiotherapy </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Dental </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Optical </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Maternity </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><b>Life insurance </b>: Private</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </body>
```

Comment: What's `sortElements`?  Is it a plugin?  If so, which one?  If it's your code, then should be straightforward.  First, add a class to your `tr` to know which is a "sub-row" (sibling row?) then exclude it from the sort `table.find("tr:not(.subrow)").find("td")...` then in the part that moves, also move the `.next()` row.

Comment: I've added sortElements function to my snippet. Can you please provide me further guidance on where to edit the code to return the subrow with the parent itself

Comment: @freedomn-m Would you please help me to do this